# Check if a date is in between collection of Date Periods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to find if a given date falls between a collection of periods
I have a period class with start and end dates, and a date to check if it is in the collection of periods. Here is the sample code to work with.

```
public class Period
{
    public Guid PeriodId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }        
}

...
// main class

public Collection<Period> Periods = Collection of Periods ;
public DateTime TimeToCheck = somedatevalue;

public bool IsTimeInGivenPeriods(TimeToCheck, Periods)
{
     if(TimeToCheck is in Periods)
         return true;
     else
         retrun false;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a for or foreach or any loop over the collection, instead use the extension methods

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the date is within one or more of the periods in your collection?

Comment: What does the type of method (regular or extension) have to do with the implementation of the search?

Comment: Also, what type is `Collection<T>`? Do you mean `List<Period>`?

Comment: Your pseudo-code doesn't make clear what you want (which often is the case with pseudo code). Do you want to filter out all periods that contain `TimeToCheck` or is it enough that *any* of them contain this date?

Comment: @RufusL check if the given TimeToCheck is between the Start and End of each Period object in the list of Period objects. Return true if at least there is atleast one period object that satisfies the condition else false.

Comment: @RufusL I'm using IQueryable in the search, so i wanted an extension method.

Comment: @RufusL Yes, A List

Comment: @GertArnold check if the given TimeToCheck is between the Start and End of each Period object in the list of Period objects. Return true if at least there is atleast one period object that satisfies the condition else false

Comment: So you have your answer below, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You could define it as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static void IsTimeInGivenPeriods<IEnumerable<Period>>(this IEnumerable<Period> Periods, DateTime TimeToCheck )
    {
         return Periods?.Any(p=>  p.Start <= TimeToCheck && p.End < TimeToCheck )  ?? false;
    }
```

now you will be able to do this:

```
...
// main class

public Collection<Period> Periods = Collection of Periods ;
public DateTime TimeToCheck = somedatevalue;

var boolResult = Periods.IsTimeInGivenPeriods(TimeToCheck );
```

Comment: Presumably `Collection` isn't `List` so perhaps you should change your parameter to be `IEnumerable<Period>`?

Comment: @NetMage True, didn't think of that. I'll edit it in

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the date is greater than or equal to any period's start date and less than or equal to that period's end date:

```
public static bool IsTimeInGivenPeriods(DateTime timeToCheck, IEnumerable<Period> periods)
{
    return periods?.Any(p => timeToCheck >= p.Start && timeToCheck <= p.End) ?? false;
}
```

If you want an extension method, then you could implement it like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool ContainsDate(this IEnumerable<Period> periods, DateTime timeToCheck)
    {
        return periods?.Any(p => timeToCheck >= p.Start && timeToCheck <= p.End) ?? false;
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var periods = new List<Period>
{
    new Period {Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)}
};

// Use the extension method to see if today's date is in any period
var todayExists = periods.ContainsDate(DateTime.Today); // returns true
```